# Convert accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath to didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, xcode, segue, didselectrowatindexpath

I currently have this method implemented

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
// Search the View controller form the cell specified.
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
self.cellPhrase = cell.textLabel.text;
NSLog(@"cellPhrase %@", self.cellPhrase);

// Perform the segue.
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"phraseSelectionSegue" sender:self];
```

}

Which works however it means that I can only the small I icon rather than the whole cell to proceed so I wanted to change to didSelectRowAtIndexPath

So I implemented the method

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Search the View controller form the cell specified.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.cellPhrase = cell.textLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"cellPhrase %@", self.cellPhrase);

    // Perform the segue.
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"phraseSelectionSegue" sender:self];
}
```

I then moved the Accessory to Disclosure indicator and made sure my Segue push Selection Segue.

However when I run the application it doesn't seem to run through.

I was wondering if anyone could spot why.

Comment: Do you get an error?  Does that code get executed?  What is the value of the `allowsSelection` property of your tableView?

Comment: Brilliant thanks pbasdf I'd forgotten about the allowsSelection property. Please could you write it as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Have added as an answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the value of `allowsSelection` for your tableView.  Cells will not trigger `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` if the value is false.